# error when substitute curdate to date

Tags: mysql

i have two table

```
reg_data `('date','session','anem_reading') 
`velocity `('date', 'run','velocity')
```

i write query for when insert data in day wise e.g when date = today,  session= morning , today anem_reading select  and yesterday anem_reading select where session='morning' and subtract today value by yeasterday value and insert in to velocity table with yesterday date as run that subtract value. that value divide by 24 insert as velocity to velocity table. 
this is my query it is work well

```
`insert  into velocity (date,run,velocity)
select  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY),((select anem_reading from reg_data where  date=CURDATE() and session='morning')-(select anem_reading from reg_data where  date=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)  and session='morning')) as run ,round((((select   anem_reading from reg_data where  date=CURDATE() and  session='morning')- (select anem_reading from reg_data where  date= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) and  session='morning')) /24 ),1) as velocity from reg_data where session='morning' and date=CURDATE();`
```

i want to run that query to previous data i change it like this

```
`insert  into velocity (date,run,velocity) select  DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL 1 DAY),((select   anem_reading from reg_data where date=date and session='morning')-(select anem_reading from reg_data where date=DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL 1 DAY)  and session='morning')) as run ,round((((select   anem_reading from reg_data where date=date and session='morning')-(select anem_reading from reg_data where date= DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL 1 DAY) and session='morning')) /24 ),1) as velocity from reg_data where session='morning' and date=date;`
```

but error display "subquery return more than one raw " how can i change it specially i think problem in " where date=date".

Comment: @naveen goyal can you help me plese help me

Comment: error message show that sub query return more then on record.you can use limit clause LIMIT 1 for remove the error.

Comment: @naveen goyal where should i add "LIMIT 1"

Comment: you have to track which sub query returning more then on row. you can simply run single sub query direct on database that may give you idea which one fetching more then one result.